# Firebase authentication flow for backend

Tags: firebase, go

So I started a test project with Golangg which I expore different technologies and got into some google firebase for authentication provider for users. I implemented the flow with registering users which require user/password. After that I wanted to do login (only backend vie rest api) turns out you can't since go verify user by user/password you need the google sdk works with iOS Android Web C++ Unity. The only work around i could do is get user by ID which i saved in my db then issue custom token, which then needs to be verified by method

```
signInWithCustomToken
```

but this is not implemented in the Golang lib, you need to call rest api for this

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=[API KEY]
```

but there is a function for that in js. So if I only want to do the whole service backend I seems I can't do authentication with google Firebase.

How this whole flow should look like implementing only backend service?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to log in from your backend service?

As far as I know, [Password-Based Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) requires you to directly log in the user right from the client sided app.

You still can [verify the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) from the backend side, but it is possible after you get the token from firebase auth.